# How to manage a customize for returning users in dialogflow fullfilment?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Following the design tips on action-on-google developer platform, I'm trying to give a custom welcome response for users who come back in a Google Assistant Voice app. 
https://developers.google.com/actions/design/tips

To proceed, i started by switch My Default Welcome intent in Dialogflow in the Fullfilment mode. Then deploy my code on firebase. It's work well when i ask for a name permission, but when I try to input the  'AppRequest.User lastSeen', my app shut down? 
Maybe you know what i missed in my code?

```html
'use strict';

const {
  dialogflow,
  Permission,
} = require('actions-on-google');

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  const welcome = (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.last.seen) {
    conv.ask(`Hey you're back...`);
  } else {
    conv.ask('Welcome to World Cities Trivia!...');
  }
}});

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the code in your welcome Intent Handler doesn't actually do anything.

You setup the handler

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  ...
});
```

but inside your handler you create *another* function

```
  const welcome = (conv) => {
    if (conv.user.last.seen) {
      conv.ask(`Hey you're back...`);
    } else {
      conv.ask('Welcome to World Cities Trivia!...');
    }
  }
```

that never gets called. It isn't clear why you have this inner function, since it isn't necessary. You just need the body of *that* function in the outer one. So it can look something like this, perhaps:

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  if (conv.user.last.seen) {
    conv.ask(`Hey you're back...`);
  } else {
    conv.ask('Welcome to World Cities Trivia!...');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read it from the conv object, it represents a turn in the conversation and exposes the attributes of the individual requests: [`conv.user.last`](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation.user.html#last).